# Unsigned lower filter device driver on USB hub

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I am experimenting with lower filter device drivers.  I have Windows 10 configured to allow unsigned drivers.

I can install a lower filter device driver on a my USB device.  I do that using an INF file.  The driver works but it doesn't quite do what I want.  To do what I want I have to put the filter on the USB hub instead.

But I am having difficulty getting a filter to run on a Hub device.

I have modified the driver so that it forwards everything and reinstalled it with the INF as before.

I have then edited the registry entry (in the Enum section) for the hub device adding a LowerFilters key specifying the same filter device driver that runs on my USB device.  If I now disconnect and reconnect the hub I get a Blue Screen with a Stop Code of 'WDF Violation'.

Is this likely to be because my filter driver is not signed?  The hub's function driver will of course be signed so there is a mismatch there.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x10d---wdf-violation

Answer (score 0):

Luke's comment pointed me in the right direction.

There were no parameters displayed on the Blue Screen.  In order to see the parameters I needed to open c:\windows\memory.dmp. I used WinDbg for this:  File->Open Crash Dump.  Then I had to click on the !analyze link.

Paramenter 1 was 5 and parameter 2 was 0 so the crash was caused by a null object handle.

(WinDbg.exe was located in c:\program files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64)